# Documentar trechos de código e anotações

Tags: documentação, metodologia

Gostaria de saber se alguém conhece alguma ferramenta para documentar trechos e anotações de código separado por uma árvore ou tópicos (Tecnologias por exemplo) referentes?

Gostaria de algo parecido com o https://devdocs.io/ mas com a opção de vir zerado, para que eu vá construindo aos poucos "minha" documentação de código personalizada.

Alguém poderia me indicar opções de soluções para este fim?

Comment: Já conhece o site AlternativeTo ? É uma plataforma onde você procurar por uma aplicação e ele traz resultados de aplicações similares. [AlternativeTo DevDocs](https://alternativeto.net/software/devdocs/)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Andrey, contudo, já havia pesquisado no site AlternativeTo, porém, as opções que me foram apresentadas lá são iguais ao DevDocs.io, ou seja são opções onde a documentação já vem pronta e eu não consigo personalizar a minha própria documentação. Mesmo assim valeu pela resposta!